# Grey Screen displayed and unplayable file opencv2-python

Tags: python, opencv

Things to know

- When the window pops up to show me the frame, its grey.
- The Webcam light goes off
- A file is created, it's just unplayable (even in vlc)
- File seems to have a decent file size (I think) 8kb for 5 seconds

```
class Camera:
    # Increase the scope of these variables to the class level
    video = None   
    vid_codec = None
    outputFilePath = None
    resolutionX = None
    resolutionY = None # Video Resolution
    fps = 30.0
    # Constructor
    def __init__(self, _outputFilePath, _resolutionX, _resolutionY, _fps, _videoCaptureSetting = 0):
        self.outputFilePath = os.path.dirname(_outputFilePath) # takes our string and converts it to a file path
        if not os.path.exists(self.outputFilePath):
            # If the directory already exists, we don't create it 
            # but we can still access it later on obviously
            # stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-can-i-safely-create-a-nested-directory
            os.makedirs(self.outputFilePath, exist_ok=True) # Creates the nested directories needed by the user

        # Zero is external Camera
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(_videoCaptureSetting) # Defaults to zero
        self.resolutionX = _resolutionX
        self.resolutionY = _resolutionY
        self.fps = _fps
        self.vid_codec = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MPEG")


    def record(self, secondsToRecord, _filename):
        output = cv2.VideoWriter(self.outputFilePath + _filename + '.avi', self.vid_codec, self.fps, (self.resolutionX , self.resolutionY))
        timeEnd = time.time() + (secondsToRecord) # NOTE: is not monotomic time, and will not adjust itself for machine lock
        print(self.video.isOpened())
        while time.time() <= timeEnd:
            # Capture each frame of webcam video
            ret, frame = self.video.read()
            output.write(frame)
            cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)
        output.release() # Closes the file
        cv2.destroyAllWindows
    def disconnectCamera(self):
        self.video.release()
```

and this is what I use to execute it

```
cam = Camera('./swag/cool/', 1280, 720, 30)

cam.record(5, 'myVideo')
print("Done Recording")
cam.disconnectCamera()
```

Comment: It should be `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)` in case if you wanted to keep the frame resolution captured by camera dynamic by the used then `cap.set(3,1280)` `cap.set(4,720)`. Writing `numpy array` to video in opencv is not efficient used [ffmpeg-python](https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/). In my case I was able to reduce a `150MB` file which the opencv generated to `20MB` to `60MB` based the video quality reduced for the task using `ffmpeg-python`.

Comment: @SanthoshDhaipuleChandrakanth so you are saying use FFmpeg-python to actually get process the video, but use cv2 to pull in the video from the webcam?